# How to use "TextLayoutView" of Instagram in improving TextView Rendering on Android

Tags: android, textview, rendering, instagram

To improve TextView rendering in Instagram, the engineers in Instagram provide a hack in [here](http://instagram-engineering.tumblr.com/post/114508858967/improving-comment-rendering-on-android),they use a custom view(TextLayoutView) to cache the text.Layout, but in this post, they don't give us a demo or tell us how to use it, so if I want to use this hack, how could I do?

Comment: I created GitHub Repo for it. https://github.com/Kishanjvaghela/TextLabel

Answer (score 3):

This is my simple  implementation：

**TextLayoutView：**

```
public class TextLayoutView extends View {

private Layout mLayout;

public TextLayoutView(Context context) {
    this(context, null);
}

public TextLayoutView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    this(context, attrs, 0);
}

public TextLayoutView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    setFocusable(true);
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    long t1=System.currentTimeMillis();
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    canvas.save();
    if (mLayout != null) {
        canvas.translate(getPaddingLeft(), getPaddingTop());
        mLayout.draw(canvas);
    }

    canvas.restore();
    long t2=System.currentTimeMillis();
    Log.i("TEST", "onDraw::"+(t2-t1));
}

@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    long t1=System.currentTimeMillis();
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    if (mLayout != null) {
        setMeasuredDimension(
                getPaddingLeft() + getPaddingRight() + mLayout.getWidth(),
                getPaddingTop() + getPaddingBottom() + mLayout.getHeight());
    }
    long t2=System.currentTimeMillis();
    Log.i("TEST", "onMeasure::"+(t2-t1));
}


public void setTextLayout(Layout layout) {
    mLayout = layout;
    requestLayout();
}}
```

you can use it just this:

```
    @Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ......
    viewHolder.textView.setTextLayout(getLayout(mList.get(position)));
    return convertView;
}
    private final Map<String, Layout> mLayoutMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, Layout>();
private Layout getLayout(String str) {
    Layout layout = mLayoutMap.get(str);
    if (layout == null) {
        TextPaint textPaint = new TextPaint();
        textPaint.setTextSize(20);
        layout = new StaticLayout(str, textPaint, width, Alignment.ALIGN_CENTER,
                1.0f, 0.0f, true);
        mLayoutMap.put(str, layout);
    }
    return layout;
}
```

Comment: I created GitHub Repo for It. https://github.com/Kishanjvaghela/TextLabel